# How to dispatch an action and show the data in the app.js using react/redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I don't know how to load the data of the fetchLatestAnime action in the react app.js file.

My mission is to show the endpoint data that I am doing fetch.

I have already implemented the part of the reducers and action, which you can see in the part below. The only thing I need is to learn how to display the data.

**App.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

**actions/types.js**

```js
export const FETCHING_ANIME_REQUEST = 'FETCHING_ANIME_REQUEST';
export const FETCHING_ANIME_SUCCESS = 'FETCHING_ANIME_SUCCESS';
export const FETCHING_ANIME_FAILURE = 'FETCHING_ANIME_FAILURE';
```

**actions/animesActions.js**

```js
import{
  FETCHING_ANIME_FAILURE,
  FETCHING_ANIME_REQUEST, 
  FETCHING_ANIME_SUCCESS
} from './types';

import axios from 'axios';


export const fetchingAnimeRequest = () => ({
  type: FETCHING_ANIME_REQUEST
});

export const fetchingAnimeSuccess = (json) => ({
  type: FETCHING_ANIME_SUCCESS,
  payload: json
});

export const fetchingAnimeFailure = (error) => ({
  type: FETCHING_ANIME_FAILURE,
  payload: error
});

export const fetchLatestAnime = () =>{
  return async dispatch =>{
    dispatch(fetchingAnimeRequest());
    try{
      let res = await axios.get('https://animeflv.chrismichael.now.sh/api/v1/latestAnimeAdded');
      let json = await res.data;
      dispatch(fetchingAnimeSuccess(json));
    }catch(error){
      dispatch(fetchingAnimeFailure(error));
    }
  };
};
```

**reducers/latestAnimeReducers.js**

```js
import {
  FETCHING_ANIME_FAILURE,
  FETCHING_ANIME_REQUEST,
  FETCHING_ANIME_SUCCESS
} from '../actions/types';


const initialState = {
  isFetching: false,
  errorMessage: '',
  latestAnime: []
};

const latestAnimeReducer = (state = initialState , action) =>{
  switch (action.type){
    case FETCHING_ANIME_REQUEST:
      return{
        ...state,
        isFetching: true,
      }
    case FETCHING_ANIME_FAILURE:
      return{
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        errorMessage: action.payload
      }
    case FETCHING_ANIME_SUCCESS:
      return{
        ...state,
        isFetching: false,
        latestAnime: action.payload
      }
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default latestAnimeReducer;
```

**reducers/index.js**

```js
import latestAnimeReducers from './latestAnimeReducers'
import {combineReducers} from 'redux';

const reducers = combineReducers({
  latestAnimeReducers
});

export default reducers;
```

**index.js**

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import resolvers from './redux/reducers/index';
import {createStore , applyMiddleware} from 'redux';
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const REDUX_DEV_TOOLS = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__ && window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION__()
const createStoreWithMiddleware = applyMiddleware(thunk)(createStore);
const store = createStoreWithMiddleware(resolvers , REDUX_DEV_TOOLS)

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ideally, this is how your app.js should look like. I created a working codesandbox for you [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-kalam-qu2ik). Your initial latestAnime state was an empty array but the action payload you set to it is an object, so remember to pass payload.anime like i have done in the sandbox.

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { fetchLatestAnime } from "./redux/actions/animesActions";
const App = props => {
  const { fetchLatestAnime, isFetching, latestAnime, errorMessage } = props;
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchLatestAnime();
  }, [fetchLatestAnime]);

  console.log(props);
  if (isFetching) {
    return <p>Loading</p>;
  }

  if (!isFetching && latestAnime.length === 0) {
    return <p>No animes to show</p>;
  }

  if (!isFetching && errorMessage.length > 0) {
    return <p>{errorMessage}</p>;
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {latestAnime.map((anime, index) => {
        return <p key={index}>{anime.title}</p>;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapState = state => {
  return {
    isFetching: state.latestAnimeReducers.isFetching,
    latestAnime: state.latestAnimeReducers.latestAnime,
    errorMessage: state.latestAnimeReducers.errorMessage
  };
};

const mapDispatch = dispatch => {
  return {
    fetchLatestAnime: () => dispatch(fetchLatestAnime())
  };
};

export default connect(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(App);
```

Comment: I thank you very much for your help and your contribution .. It helped me a lot.I liked the idea that you also included hooks in redux ... Tremendous combination.

Comment: If I want to do the same to show the data in another component that is not App.js, the logic would be the same, right?

Comment: Yes please. Everything will be the same

Comment: infact, react-redux library now have hooks in their api. You can read here for more https://react-redux.js.org/next/api/hooks